# MVC Ajax.BeginForm JavaScript parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an AJAX form where the url id needs to be from JavaScript

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Add","Comments", new { ArticleID = 3 }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="Comments"}))
```

Where `ArticleID = 3` should be replaced so that the ArticleID value is set equal to the result of a called Javascript function. Something like

**JS:**

```
function GetArticleID()
{
      return 3;
}
```

**Razor:**

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Add","Comments", new { ArticleID = GetArticleID() }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="Comments"}))
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Add(int ArticleID, Comment model)
{

}
```

How can I use JavaScript function result as BeginForm parameter?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i use javacript function result as BeginForm parameter?

Comment: Add that to your question so the users can understand it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `@using(Ajax.BeginForm("` will be executed by razor on server. At that time it does not have any knowledge of the javascript methods in your client browser. So you cannot mix a javascript function there.

I prefer to write clean custom code to do the ajax form submit (instead of using `Ajax.BeginForm`) because it allows me to customize any way i want.

Keep your form as a normal form.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Add","Comments"))
{
   <input type="hidden" name="ArticleId" id="ArticleId" value=""/>
   <input name="CommentText" type="text" />
   <input type="submit" id="saveCmntBtn" />
}
```

Now listen to the `click` event of the submit button. Assign the ArticleId  value to the input field, get the serialized version of the form and post to server. You may use jQuery `serialize()` method to get the serialized version of your form.

```
$(function(){

  $("#saveCmntBtn").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#ArticleId").val(GetArticleID());
     var f=$(this).closest("form");
     $.post(f.attr("action"),f.serialize(),function(res){
       $("#Comments").append(res);
     });
  });

});
```